# VBA to copy-paste multiple columns across different workbooks

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to copy and paste multiple columns from a workbook to another. I tried to adapt a code that I had to copy-paste certain cells within the same workbook, but I keep having the error "Script out of range".
The workbook I want to copy, might have a filtered range, but it shouldn't be a problem I understand? I do not mind if it copies only the column filtered area or all the results.

Please could you advise where I went wrong in the code? I tried to remove filters, without using "with / end with" but no success at all

```
Dim wbCopy As Workbook
Dim wbPaste As Workbook

On Error Resume Next
    Workbooks("Shipping.xlsx").Close SaveChanges:=False
On Error GoTo 0

Set wbCopy = Workbooks.Open("Q:\Test\Shipping.xlsx", UpdateLinks:=3)
Set wbCopy = wbCopy.Worksheets("List")
Set wbPaste = ThisWorkbook

With wbPaste.Worksheets("Shipping")
    .Columns("A").Value = wbCopy.Columns("C").Value
    .Columns("B").Value = wbCopy.Columns("D").Value
    .Columns("C").Value = wbCopy.Columns("E").Value
    .Columns("D").Value = wbCopy.Columns("F").Value
    .Columns("E").Value = wbCopy.Columns("N").Value
    .Columns("F").Value = wbCopy.Columns("O").Value
    .Columns("G").Value = wbCopy.Columns("P").Value
    .Columns("H").Value = wbCopy.Columns("Q").Value
    .Columns("I").Value = wbCopy.Columns("S").Value
End With

wbCopy.Close SaveChanges:=False
```

Comment: wbCopy is dim´ed as workbook, but you assign a worksheet to it

Comment: I tried to remove the line where I assign a sheet, and change the copy-paste rows to .Columns("A").Value = wbCopy.Worksheets(""List"").Columns("C").Value but still the same error

Comment: just curious from your comment above : `wbCopy.Worksheets(""List"")` ---> is this intentional that the word list is in between double double-quotes ? Shouldn't it be `wbCopy.Worksheets("List")` ? Please CMIIW.

Comment: My mistake in the double quotes, but even with the correct "List" it doesn't work

Comment: If you add this line `.activate` right after `With wbPaste.Worksheets("Shipping")`, does it give you the expected result ?

Comment: Same error _subscript out of range_ and the debugger stops on the first row `.Columns("A").Value = wbCopy.Worksheets("List").Columns("C").Value`

Comment: That might mean the sheet ```wbCopy.Worksheets("List")``` doesn't exist. Trying to refer to a non-existent sheet will generate a subscript out of range error (the sheet name serves as the subscript in the Worksheets collection). Verify the sheet name spelling.

Comment: So the yellow can pass `.activate` right after `With wbPaste.Worksheets("Shipping")` --- meaning you now see the sheet "Shipping" of wbPaste workbook, but then the yellow stuck at `.Columns("A").Value = wbCopy.Worksheets("List").Columns("C").Value` as it throw an error. If you add `wbCopy.Worksheets("List").activate` right after `.activate`, does it show you sheet "List" of wbCopy workbook successfully ?

Comment: Sorted! I wasn't lucky with the `.activate` but removing the filters and adding a range did the trick. For anyone interested, the ammendment was     `If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode Then
        ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
    End If
    LastRow = wsSource.Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
    .Range("A5:A" & LastRow).Value = wsSource.Range("C5:C" & LastRow).Value` Thanks!